# cartesian product of smooth manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I want to show that a finite cartesian product of smooth manifold is smooth manifold.
My approach to prove it inductively:
for $n=2$ 
Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb R^M$ be a manifolds of dimension $k$ and $ l$, respectively. For $W \subseteq \mathbb R^k$ an open set with $\phi:W\to X$ a local parameterization around $x\in X$ and $U \subseteq \mathbb R^l$ an open set with $\psi:U \to Y$ a local parameterization around $y\in Y$.
Then we can define the map $\phi \times \psi:W\times U\rightarrow X\times Y$, $\phi \times  \psi(w,u)=(\phi(w),\psi(u))$, from the open set $W\times U \subseteq \mathbb R^k \times \mathbb R^l$ to $X \times Y$.
Is my approach work ? and how can I prove that this map is defines a local parametrization around $(x,y)$ ?

Comment: your idea works and could be done without induction (just apply it on a product of $n$ manifolds). To show that it is a parametrization, just go back to the definition (and use that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are parametrizations)

Comment: Thanks.. @Didier